# python inside docker alpine image

Tags: python, docker, pip, alpine-linux

```
RUN apk add --update-cache postgresql-client python3 python3-dev py3-pip postgresql postgresql-contrib && \
  python3 -m ensurepip && \
  pip --version && \
  pip install --upgrade pip && \
  apk add py3-pip && \
  pip install awscli && \
  mkdir -p /sql-backup
```

Gives me an error during build (alpine3.7)

```
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages (40.6.2)                                                                                                                                     
Requirement already satisfied: pip in /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages (18.1)                                                                                                                                     
/bin/sh: pip: not found
```

Comment: Change the `pip` command to `pip3` and see if it works, You could also try using `python3 -m pip --version`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `pip3` instead of `pip` .
It's my initial guess since very often linux default python/pip command refers to python2.